# Enumerate @font-face URLs using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-face

Is there a way of enumerating all the @font-face URLs (web font URLs) of a given HTML page using JavaScript or JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming you mean you want to find all the @font-faces specified in the stylesheet as opposed to actually USED in the HTML document itself.

Given a reasonably standard stylesheet that looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster12Regular';
    src: url('fonts/lobster_1.2-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/lobster_1.2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/lobster_1.2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/lobster_1.2-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/lobster_1.2-webfont.svg#Lobster12Regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerRegular';
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_rg-webfont.svg#AllerRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerBold';
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_bd-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_bd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_bd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_bd-webfont.svg#AllerBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AllerLight';
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_lt-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/aller_std_lt-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_lt-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_lt-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/aller_std_lt-webfont.svg#AllerLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster12Regular';
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'AllerRegular';
}
```

Then the following HTML (with inlined Javascript) will more or less do the trick:

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>Hello</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">

var pattern=/url\(.*?\)/g;
for (var i=0;i<document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length;i++)
{
    var urls=document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[i].cssText.match(pattern);
    if (urls)
    {
        for (var j=0;j<urls.length;j++)
        {
            alert(urls[j]);
        }
    }
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

With some caveats:

Firstly, one of main ways to specify @font-face relies on specifying the src twice, this technique will only pick up the second src.

I've not tested this cross-browser but it works on my browser and pops up an alert box with each font url.

The hard coded [0] makes it only look at the first stylesheet (in this example there is only one). It's reasonably trivial to write yet another loop to loop over all stylesheets if required but seemed like overkill for this example.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious to you, but I want to mention a problem of this and [@Orwellophile's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19343013/2590616). It will work on same domain stylesheets, only. If you try to read the rules of a stylesheet on a different domain, e.g. on a cdn, you run into a cross domain policy in Chrome and get a script error ("SecurityError: The operation is insecure.") in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. There only seems to be this technique: http://paulirish.com/2009/font-face-feature-detection/ to detect if `@font-face` can be used, but not to detect which fonts *are* being used. Short of parsing all of the CSS code server-side (or at least server-side assisted) there's no way to do what you want, not with just JS and jQuery. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I just wrote up for my own use, works fine with Chrome, haven't tested with other browsers - but seems fairly standard to me.

It requires jquery, and will identify all fonts in-use, and their sources (if webfonts).

Note, it does not adequately handle variations on a font (different 'bold' version), and also cannot handle styles with multiple fonts defined (eg: font-family: fonta, fontb, fontc).

```
jQuery.fn.elementText = function() {
    return $(this)  
            .clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text()
            .replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '')
            ;
};

Font = function(family, src) {
    // In order to properly categorise complex font setups, weight and style need to be 
    // considered as part of a unique font. (TODO)
    this.family = family;
    this.src = src;
    this.weight = null;
    this.style = null;
};

Font.prototype.toString = function() {
    return '[Font ' + this.family + ': ' + this.src + ']';
};


var fontNames = {};
var fontObjects = [];

$(':visible').each(function (k, v) {
    var $v = $(v);
    var font;
    if ($v.elementText().length) {
        font = $v.css('font-family');
        // TODO: seperate by comma, remove quotes
        fontNames[font] = font;
    }
});

for (var sheet=0; sheet < document.styleSheets.length; sheet++)
for (var i=0; i<document.styleSheets[sheet].cssRules.length; i++)
{
    var rule = document.styleSheets[sheet].cssRules[i];
    if (rule instanceof CSSFontFaceRule) {
        if (fontNames[rule.style.fontFamily])
            fontObjects.push(
                    new Font(rule.style.fontFamily, rule.style.src) );
    }
}

fontObjects.forEach( function(v) { console.log(v.toString()); });
```

Sample output (here you can see an example of what happens when you have different 'bold', 'italic' etc font-style defines):

```
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-BookItalic.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-Book.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-MediumItalic.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-Medium.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-BoldItalic.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-Bold.otf)]
[Font 'ITC Legacy Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/LegacySansStd-Ultra.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-LightIta.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-Light.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-Book.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-SemiboldIta.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-Semibold.otf)]
[Font 'Ocean Sans Std': url(http://localhost/~admin/tmp/fonts/OceanSansStd-Bold.otf)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get font-family with variants and URL's.
Following is the code in jQuery

```js
var fontArray = [];
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key={your key}&sort=popularity", {}, function (data) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
        count++
        fontArray.push(value);
    });
});
```